# How to escape the period (dot) character in awk?

Tags: awk, escaping

I am using gawk on Windows 8.1 (from GnuWin32)

How to escape the period (".") character?

I tried with "\." and "\x2e" and it doesn't work

my input file (z.txt) is this:

```
fox.doc
bear.jpg
abcjpg
```

and I'm trying to find .jpg files with this script (z.awk):

```
  { printf $0; if (match($0, /\x2ejpe?g$/)) printf " - Jpeg image"; print "" }
```

I run this script from a batch file (z.bat):

```
cat z.txt | gawk -f z.awk
```

It doesn't matter if I'm using "\." or "\x2e" or ".", it will still match any character. The output I got is

```
fox.doc
bear.jpg - Jpeg image
abcjpg - Jpeg image
```

In the output, the last line should be:

```
abcjpg
```

I've uploaded the scripts here - https://github.com/FrostShock/WinScripts/tree/main/ZZZ

Comment: `\.` should work. Also `[.]`. Perhaps your shell is mangling the program before gawk receives it.

Comment: It is a stand alone program - "script.awk" the shell can't mess it. But it works with [.] - therefore this is the correct answer - to properly escape the period character, you must use [.]

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you have a file named `script.awk` with contents `printf $0; if (match($0, /\x2ejpe*g/)) printf " - Jpeg image"; print ""` that you're executing as `awk -f script.awk fox.doc` but if so, your awk script contains syntax errors and if not then we don't know what you're actually executing. Please [edit] you're question to show a [mcve] that includes an actual minimal, complete script you want help with.

Comment: Ok, I modified the question and I've also uploaded the files on GitHub

Comment: @jhnc - the [.] is the real solution for escaping the dot character in awk in windows. Can you add your response as an answer so I can make it the accepted answer?

Comment: It's not really a solution; backslash is needed in other places in awk scripts. Btw, `\x2e` doesn't work because it is equivalent to `.` not `\.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk you must use the compatibility mode (`-c`) if you want the escape sequences to be interpreted literally:

```
$ man awk
...
In  compatibility  mode,  the  characters represented by octal and
hexadecimal escape sequences are treated literally when used in regular
expression constants.  Thus, /a\52b/ is equivalent to /a\*b/.
```

But I am very surprized that `\.` did not work as expected. There must be something else that happens in what you do not show. Try, maybe:

```
awk '/\.jpe?g$/ {$(NF+1) = " - Jpeg image"} {print}'
```

Demo:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "foo.doc" "bear.jpg" "abcjpg.txt" | \
  awk '/\.jpe?g$/ {$(NF+1) = " - Jpeg image"} {print}'
abcjpg.txt
bear.jpg  - Jpeg image
foo.doc
```

Comment: It works like this but it doesn't work when using match(). The input file and the script are more complex, I have to use match(). I guess I should rewrite the title into "How to escape the period (dot) character in match() function in awk?" Also the input must contain a line which ends in sabc where s is any character except dot

Comment: the -c switch doesn't work in the GnuWin32 awk

Comment: @JoeJobs Well, in this case GnuWin32 awk is not really a port of GNU awk, despite the name. I just tested `match($0, /\.jpe?g/))` with GNU awk and it works like a charm on your example. As I do not have a Windows box I cannot investigate more, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

why not just cage it `[.]` ? This way you never have to worry about how many layers of `\\` is being munched off along the way.

> ```
> gawk -ce 'gsub("[.]", "\f{ & }\f")^_'
> ```

```
test.123.456
test
    { . }
         123
            { . }
                 456
```